# Input field allows only numbers and hyphens and within a specific format

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that helps me insure that the input will be only numbers.

However I also need to restrict this number to be within a specific format 0000-00, using sort of alert or maybe return values false or better solution ..

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)' id="class" name="class" maxlength="7" size="15px" placeholder="Ex. 1504-03" required>

<script>
            function validate(evt) {
              var theEvent = evt || window.event;
              var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
              key = String.fromCharCode( key );
              var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
              if( !regex.test(key) ) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
              }
            }
        </script>
```

Your help for best practices is much appreciated

Comment: You mean the number should contain hiphen after 4 digits

Comment: So the input will not be only numbers

Comment: yes i need it to be in the format of this example 1507-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following link:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

It explains how to add a mask to an input text area.
Hope this helps :)

Admin Alex

Comment: Link is broken... it says "Error establishing a database connection."

Answer (score 1):

You can have a regex within your HTML with the [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" id="class" name="class" maxlength="7" size="15px" placeholder="Ex. 1504-03" required>
```

**Note:** The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.